# Performance of JSF Composite components

Tags: performance, jquery, jsf-2, java-ee-6, composite-component

Since a few weeks we have performance problems in our web applications. First we thought the problems belongs to large DOM. Large DOM isn´t really good but thats not the main perfomance problem.

The problem are the composite components. The last weeks we developed core composite components to reduce code redundancy and have centralized places for changes. We replaced each individual implementation within our application(s) with the composite component.

**First test case:**
We´ve created a single page with a commandButton, a outputText and 50 composite components that contains a p:dialog. Click on the button just updates the outputText component (Ajax). 
The update takes about 1.5 seconds.

**Second test:**
Same page with commandButton and outputText component. Instead of using the composite components we´ve added the p:dialogs directly to the page.
The update takes 0.06 seconds.

Is there something wrong with using composite components? I can´t find similar threads that are related to performance problems with composite components.

Comment: We use Mojarra 2.1 impl.

Comment: What version exactly? It's currently at 2.1.4 (and 2.1.5 is "half" released).

Comment: I must have a look tomorrow but we use JSF bundled with Glassfish 3.1.1 . I think it is 2.1.3 but i´m not sure.

Comment: We use Mojarra 2.1.3 bundled with GF3.1.1. Some hints?

Answer (score 1):

There were some performance bugs in Mojarra version up to 2.1.21, so use myfaces, until mojarra bugs get fixed, For more info visit http://blog.oio.de/2013/05/06/jsf-performance-tuning/